# Laravel Session push "to logged user not global"

Tags: session, laravel-4

I am saving data in session (correct and wrong answers, i am doing it this way because before i save them to database i have to check some criteria and also user can pause the question to log in and continue later) but i want to save them for each user not global for all users. And because of that i am having problem if i log in with different user the session data from previous user will still be there.

This is how i push to session but this is global (every user can access it)

```
 Session::push('uncorrect', array('exam_id' => $exam, 'question_id' => $question, 'answer_id' => 0));
```

This is an example of Logged user in session

```
login_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc": 1,
```

So my question is how to save Session for current user, not all users?

Comment: Sounds like you're not clearing session data when logging out

Comment: I tought of that myself, but the problem that i might have is what if user didnt log out by pressing on "log out button". User might be inactive and laravel will remove user session but not my session.

Comment: I know this is probably a stupid question, but i am rather new to laravel (i dont understand "advanced" things). And also to ask does laravel destroy sessions or does php (configured in php.ini)?

Comment: The PHP session will remain active for the duration of the browser session, as will Laravel's session. When logging out, you would typically want to clear all session values or regenerate the id. So, in Laravel, you can use `Session::flush()` to clear values, or `Session::regenerate()` to get a new ID.

Comment: Oh so that how it works, Thank you for explaning. Can you put it as answer so i can check it. I used `Session::flush()` on logout and also write about sesions you said in previous comment.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, but to explain fully: the Laravel session remains active for the duration of the browser session - that is, as long as the browser retains the session cookie. This is irrespective of different users being logged into your application in the same browser session.

When logging a user out, you would typically want to clear all session values or regenerate the ID. So, in Laravel, you can use `Session::flush()` to clear values, or `Session::regenerate()` to get a new ID.